# how do I select a single tag in the middle of many of the same in CSS?

Tags: css

I have a single "p" tag inside a "div' tag along with many other "p" tags. So how do i select just that single tag in the middle of all those other ones one so i can change its style in CSS? I'm very new to html and CSS, so, sorry if this is a stupid question.
Thank you!

Comment: put a class on it, e.g. `div p.myspecialp { ... }` and `<p class="myspecialp">`

Comment: Do you have any sample HTML and/or CSS?

Comment: ***sorry if this is a stupid question***, well actually people here have their own ways of dealing with bad questions, some will silently downvote, some will downvote with comment, others will only leave comment ... So don't worry about that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `:nth-child`. So the 2nd `<p>` inside the `<div>` would be `div p:nth-child(2)`.

Or like Marc B said in the comments, add a class to it.

```
<div>
    <p>Hello, </p><p class='lionel'>is it me you're</p><p> looking for?</p>
</div>
```

You could find that middle `<p>` with

```
div p.lionel {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Or to target the same `<p>` using `:nth-child()`

```
div p:nth-child(2){
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd add a class or an id to the element.

If, for some reason you can't add any attributes, you can use the :nth-child selector to grab it. Something like `div > p:nth-child(5)` would grab the fifth match of the `div > p` selector.

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child), everything back to IE7 supports :nth-child, with the exception that IE7 and 8 require the page to be in standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if you have a group of elements and want to specifically change the style of one of them, you should add a **class** or **id** to it.

If you have this and want to target the second **p**:

```
<div>
    <p>...</p>
    <p class="special">...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
<div>
```

You can target it by its class name.

```
.special{
    /* do stuff here */
}
```

if for whatever reason you can't add custom classes to the p's then you can use the **:nth-child** css selector, as follow:

```
div p:nth-child(2){
    /* do stuff here */
}
```